# HTML Dialog element works as expected in the UI but shows error in the console

Tags: javascript, html, dom, modal-dialog

The functionality in the UI works as expected with the modal/dialog element, but however the below error is shown in the console - "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'showModal' on 'HTMLDialogElement': The element already has an 'open' attribute, and therefore cannot be opened modally"

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well when I accidentally added the click listener on the button, that opens the modal, twice. Fixing that solved the issue.